# Hibernate Envers Get Revision right after Persisting Data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-envers

I'm using Spring JPA to persist data in my application. I also use Hibernate Envers to create a history for every record I enter into my core table. I would like to get the revision immediately after the **write** transaction, and show the user what revision was created for the change(s) s/he just made.

In other words:

Step 1: `entity -- persisted --> entity table -- envers --> audit table`

Step 2: `return me the audit version just created`

I have taken the approach of persisting the data first, and then retrieve the **latest** rev info from the audit table in a **separate call**. This will eventually be inconsistent as the number of users increases.

```
MyEntity mySavedEntity = myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);         
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
List<Number> revisions = reader.getRevisions(MyEntity .class, mySavedEntity.getId());

// ... get the latest revision and pass it back to the user ...
```

How do I attack this problem? - Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can make Envers log the version column of your entities by setting [`org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field` to `false`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers-configuration)

Then use that column and the value of the version attribute of the entity after the transaction for retrieving the revision.

Comment: I'm using `@Audited` at the class level. Are you suggesting that I use `@Version` on every field in my entity class and set that property to `false`?

Comment: No, I suggest to have a column for optimistic locking as most models do anyway, log that field with Envers by disabling the mentioned property, and than finding the correct revision from Envers by using the version property since it will change everytime Envers stores a new revision.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the ValidityAuditStrategy, you can check it [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-an-audit-log-using-hibernate-envers/), this will let you know your last valid entry and in this case get the last revision.